# New HP laptop, Ubuntu does not recognize Wireless Adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, hardware

I'm on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04), kernel 3.19.

None of the network related interfaces give me any indication that my computer is capable of detecting or connecting to WiFi networks.

This is an HP ENVY - 15t Slim Quad Laptop Product number: T1P54AV, the specs they provided me with are:

- HP TrueVision HD Webcam with Dual Digital Microphone
- 8GB DDR3L System Memory (1 Dimm)
- 1TB 5400 rpm Hard Drive
- 6-cell 47WHr Lithium-ion Battery
- Backlit Keyboard
- 6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ Quad Core Processor + Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
- Intel 802.11ac WLAN and Bluetooth(R) [1x1]
- No DVD or CD Drive
- 15.6-inch diagonal Full HD WLED-backlit IPS Display (1920x1080)

`lspci -nn` gives me:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
02:00.0  Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
```

`ifconfig` does not give me any connection other then Ethernet or lo:

```
eth0
...  
lo
...
```

`iwconfig` similarly:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The `rfkill list` output is:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lshw -C network` yields:

`*-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: dc:4a:3e:62:f2:83
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.2.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a3200000-a3200fff memory:a3000000-a3003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3100000-a3101fff`

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` yields:

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8154]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

I'm kind of lost here. I've tried several things including installing drivers backported to my kernel version but none of it changed the behaviour I've described above.

Something that I believe is of note is that I've ran archlinux on this machine before and it was able to detect my wireless card without problems during installation. I looked up the realtek wireless drivers it provides and attempted to install them from a package of backports (possibly incorrectly though and it didn't help)

*Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck here for a while.*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Actually the [Intel  8086:3165](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/3165) is your wireless adapter.  Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo rfkill list`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: `0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`

Comment: Woa! You're quick! **;-)** What's the exact model number of HP Envy?

Comment: HP ENVY - 15t Slim Quad Laptop

 Product number: T1P54AV

I'm not sure whether the product number correlates directly to the model, so I will post the specs I got in the receipt into the OP.

Comment: Searching your device ID brought me to this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/682658/intel-corporation-device-3165-wifi-doesnt-work . Seems like you have a Intel 3165, and the solution presented is to update your kernel or upgrade to 15.10.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I followed the instructions for upgrading the kernel to 4.23 minus the nvidia (i'm using an integrated intel video card) after I did it I had some expected graphical glitches I purged and reinstalled the entire X stack and it seems to work with both no graphical glitches and a working wifi now. I can't green-check your response, because it's a comment rather than answer, I'm new to this what do I do?

Comment: It's a duplicate: no action needed: it will be closed as such. @GTrawo: next time use the [Flag] button below the question when this happens again!  **;-)**

Comment: I would like to see the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` as it gives the subsystem ID of the wifi card

Comment: @Jeremy31 posted it, although I have solved the wifi problem last night via kernel upgrade (on 4.3 currently)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ndiswrapper. It allows you to install Windows drivers of wireless cards.

Before installing:

Type  `lshw -C network`  in a terminal. You can also try `lspci -vvnn` look for the wireless card. It looks like this in my terminal:

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface  
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
```

#### Installation

If you have wired access to internet:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

If you don't you can find the packages you'll need at http://packages.ubuntu.com. Here are the 3 packages you'll need:

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ndiswrapper-common
2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
3. http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ndisgtk

Now you can download the Windows driver. You can find it on the manufacturer's website and install it with ndiswrapper.

[You should also read this for more details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)

Comment: `ndiswrapper` is a last-ditch solution: only if nothing else works, should you try this solution.

Comment: I would also prefer to wait on importing windows drivers, however, I will post the output to `lshw -C network` into the OP.

Comment: @Fabby - i am also facing the same issue. Is kernel upgrade to 4.2 or 4.3 the only solution for this intel wireless 3165 wifi issue? I want to be on 14.0.4 due to some software compatibility. Don't know what all i need to make the changes for this kernel upgrade?

Comment: @Ashu: this is not a good place to put another question.  So please first look over the existing answers and if none of them work, [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this question and explain what went wrong.  **;-)**
I posted an answer that helped *some* people, but not the OP itself, and custom kernels are off-topic here...

Answer (score 1):

From your [HP ENVY Manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03943414.pdf) page 11: press the <kbd>F12</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> depending on BIOS settings) to turn on WiFi... (Do this after the computer has fully booted)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: My f12 button is lit up with the color that would indicate that wireless is already turned on. When I was on Arch it was also lit up the same color (and the wireless worked,) when I press it, it doesn't toggle colors like it's supposed to and makes absolutely no difference in the behavior of my network interfaces, so I do not believe that the problem is that the hardware is chip isn't powered, nor that I'm somehow unable to power it on using the method prescribed in the manual.

Comment: Nor [F12] on its own nor [Fn][F12]?  If not: try `sudo rflist unblock all` then...

Comment: I'm *really* going to sleep now...  To be continued, hopefully the information I requested will allow someone else to come up with a better solution then `ndiswrapper`...