# Identical mount points during upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, mount, 15.04, 15.10

I'm installing Ubuntu on a new Lenovo 700 with dual-boot. I successfully installed 15.04, but discovered that my wireless card (the Intel 3165) isn't supported. I saw this thread: [How to get my Intel Wireless 3165 to connect on 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657774/how-to-get-my-intel-wireless-3165-to-work)

I tried to install kernel 4.2 as that thread suggests, but Ubuntu froze early during the dpkg command. I decided to not mess with updating the kernel in place, and made a liveUSB of 15.10, since that version should support my wireless card.

The new boot stick works (and detects the wireless successfully), but when I ask it to upgrade 15.04 to 15.10, it tells me that

```
Identical mount points for two file systems

Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/boot/efi): /dev/nvme0n1p1 and SCSI3 (0,0,0), partition #2 (sda)

Please correct this by changing mount points.
```

I don't really know what to do here. I partitioned the hard drive successfully during the install of 15.04, and grub is handling booting into Windows without issue. Do I really have to assign a new new mount point for an upgrade?

Incidentally, if I tell it to erase 15.04 and reinstall, the installer tells me it can't create the swap space successfully.

Thanks very much for any help anyone can give.

Comment: Same problem here. Ubuntu 18.10.