# Why does internet suddenly fail on both wired and wireless connections (Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, internet, ethernet, realtek, intel-wireless

**NOTE**: This is not a duplicate of [How to get my Intel Wireless 3165 to connect on 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657774/how-to-get-my-intel-wireless-3165-to-work). That question dealt with a system (running 15.04, **kernel 3.19**) that did **not connect via wireless at all** (but presumably could connect via ethernet). The present issue deals with a system that **can connect via wifi and ethernet**, but the **internet connection drops randomly on both wireless and wired** (when either is used). In addition, both answers (which recommended upgrading to kernel 4.2) on that previous question cannot be applied to solve this issue. **16.04 already uses kernel 4.4** out of the box.

**QUESTIONS**: Why does the internet drop from wired and wireless even though they appear to remain connected? Where can I look to begin figuring this out? What diagnostics can I run to probe the wired issue?

**SUMMARY**: Internet drops every 1-30 minutes when connected via wired or wireless (i.e., this is a problem on both wired **and** wireless) even though connection icon indicates the computer is still connected.

Disconnecting and reconnecting via the connection icon resets internet temporarily until the next random drop.

Dropped internet is discovered with "The site can't be reached" screens in Chromium, or error messages when downloading/updating in Terminal, or stalled syncing in Insync application.

Internet drops more frequently on wireless than on wired.

It seems to disconnect more frequently with heavier internet use (e.g., downloading multiple files, opening several webpages in quick succession).

This is on a fresh install (yesterday) of Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 5567 (dual boot). The issue also occurs when running on Live CD.

Ethernet and WiFi both work without disconnecting in Windows 10 on the same machine, and ethernet and wifi work on other machines running Ubuntu and Windows with the same router, so it is not a hardware or router issue.

This change from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785799/on-16-04-internet-keeps-disconnecting#comment1179444_785799) did not work:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi disable_11n=1"
```

This change did not work either:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Output from

```
sudo lshw -class network

  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 79
       serial: 58:fb:84:55:21:52
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:283 memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: 18:db:f2:3c:d5:37
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:279 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df000000-df000fff memory:d0300000-d0303fff
```

Output from:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Wireless info script pasted [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24038604/).

I don't know what other diagnostics I can run for the wired connection.

Comment: @MadMike This issue is a problem on **both wired and wireless on 16.04 working intermittently**. [How to get my Intel Wireless 3165 to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/657774/how-to-get-my-intel-wireless-3165-to-work) is **no wireless on 15.04 at all**. Also, the most popular answer on that thread says to look for "no suitable firmware found" in the wireless info script, but that doesn't occur in mine. Doesn't seem the same to me.

Comment: Does the same issue appear with different internet connections, different operating systems or even different machines? In the case of the former it may be related to the OS or a driver but the in the latter two cases I'd look at the router and ISP.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for your comment. Please see above for answers to the questions you raised.
In addition, this issue cannot be an exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/657774/how-to-get-my-intel-wireless-3165-to-work for the reasons I appended to the beginning of the post above. If you disagree, please explain your reasons. Otherwise, I respectfully ask that you and the other users (who I cannot tag in a single comment) remove the duplicate tag please.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I voted to reopen. I'm no wireless adapter expert but a [search for "Intel 3156"](/search?q=intel+3165) may turn up a few interesting module options etc. to try.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you. I will keep searching.